# Entering the last modified directory

Tags: shell, directory, alias

Which command can I use to:

- Enter the last modified directory in the current directory.
- If no directory exists or is possible to enter, do nothing.

I'm looking for an alias named `ca` that will work at least in `zsh`, but also in `bash` and `ash`, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible solution:

```
alias ca='cd $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf "%T@ %p\n" | sort -n | tail -1 | cut -d" " -f2-)'
```

But it has the following problems:

- Using the output directly from `find` without using something like `print0`, which results in directories with spaces in the name to not be handled correctly.
- Entering `.` if that is the last modified directory, instead of one of the directories within `.`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work on `zsh` and `bash` as far as I know (not an alias, though):

```
ca() { 
  local dir newer

  for dir in ./*; do
    if [[ ! -d "${dir}" ]]; then
      continue
    fi
    if [[ "${dir}" -nt "${newer}" ]]; then
      newer="${dir}"
    fi
  done

  if [[ -x "${newer}" ]]; then
    cd -- "${newer}"
  fi
}
```